# Как релизовать данную задачу?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
#Старт игры!
while ships_not_destroyed:

    player = int(input('Put the number from 0 to 10:\n'))
    tries += 1

    if player > 10:
        print("Print a correct number!")
    if player in ships_board:
        hits += 1
        print('Hit!')
        ships_board.remove(player)
        ships_grave = player
    elif player == ships_grave:
        print("U already destroyed this ship!") 
    elif player not in ships_board:
        print('Miss!')
    if hits == 3:
        ships_not_destroyed = False
        print('All ships are destroyed')
```

Скажите пожалуйста, как мне правильно реализовать функцию, если игрок повторно вводит предыдущее значение, то выводится надпись(" Вы уже стреляли в эту локацию!"). Я пробовал добавить переменную в которой сохраняется значение вводимое игроком, но это не приводит к нужному результату.

Comment: как вариант: создать массив где будут храниться все отстреленные клеточки и не давать игроку стрелять в значение из этого массива

Comment: Clark Devlin я тоже думал про этот вариант, но дело в том, что надо будет массив проверять на значение введенное игроком и дело в том, что массив будет сразу проверяться и будет выводится и значение игрока и надпись (" Вы уже стреляли в эту локацию!")! Вот если бы, итерация начиналась пропуская проверку массива

Comment: добавить условие после ввода клетки: `if player in already_shooted: print('Вы уже стреляли в эту клетку')` `already_shooted` массив с уже отстреленными клетками, после каждого выстрела добавлять туда значение

Comment: Скажите, а добавление player в массив already_shooted, где в коде прописывать?

Comment: В каждом возможном условии выстрела

Comment: Почему “hint” то?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решил, вот правильный код:

```
while ships_not_destroyed:

    player = int(input('Put the number from 0 to 10:\n'))
    tries += 1

    if player in already_shooted:
    print('U already shooted in this area!')
    continue

    if player > 10:
        print("Put a correct number!")

    if player in ships_board:
        hits += 1
        print('Hint!')
        ships_board.remove(player)
        ships_grave = player
        if hits == 3:
           ships_not_destroyed = False
           print('All ships are destroyed')
        continue

    if player == ships_grave:
       print("U already destroyed this ship!")
    elif player not in ships_board:
       print('Miss!')    

   else:
       already_shooted.append(player)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
old_player = []

while ships_not_destroyed:
    player = int(input('Put the number from 0 to 10:\n'))

    if player in old_player:
        print(" Вы уже стреляли в эту локацию!")
        continue
    else:
        old_player.append(player)

    tries += 1
    ...
```

Comment: Тоже самое, только что написал! Вот только, теперь если ты попал в корабль и вводише опять ту же клетку, выдает - "Вы уже стреляли в эту локацию!", а было "U already destroyed this ship"